# How to post a message to an handle that expects a custom message structure?

Tags: delphi, message

Is there a way to post an asynchronous message as `postmessage` does? `Postmessage` expects only to receive `Lparam` and `Wparam`, how could I pass my own custom messagetag structure?

The only alternative to avoid using winapi that I know is to use a safe queue. I would like your advice to point me at the direction for a reliable and common solution for this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Declare a record type for your custom message.
2. Allocate one of these records on the heap. Initialize its members.
3. Call `PostMessage` passing the address of the record in `lParam`.
4. When the recipient has finished processing the message it deallocates it.

This only works if sender and recipient are in the same process.

Comment: Yes, I used this solution to send strings before. I was not aware that it was the same for records, though thank you, David

Comment: David, do you know how windows does, to pass the actual custom message tag as parameter? Is that way not possible for us users?

Comment: I don't understand why you mean by that

Comment: There are some messages that don't use `var message: tmessage`, instead they use another tag structure, and we don't need to use heap in this cases

Comment: Those are just for convenience. Message specific variable names. Note that the size of those records is the same.

Comment: Very interesting. Now is clear to me. Thank you again